# powershell workflow - parameter splatting not supported?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why parameter splatting won't work for a set of workflow runbooks executed in Azure Automation.

I've got 3 runbooks (super, sub, child) that are called in a nested fashion. 
They all share (generally) the same parameters. In my real-world scenario, I have multiple sub & child runbooks and I want to use splatting so I could define a hashtable once and pass it as needed, without having to list out all the params.

I've also tried using the `-PSParameterCollection` parameter. However, in Azure Automation, this appears only to be available for the topmost runbook (which already works), as it throws a parameter not found error for it in the children. The Note section [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574123.aspx#Anchor_1) says **Workflows that are nested three levels deep do not support any common parameters, including workflow common parameters**, which seems like it could be a problem, depending on how these runbooks are compiled.. but I don't think I can avoid that without limiting the reusability of the runbooks. I wouldn't expect called workflows to be compiled as nested workflows within the calling one.

The error I get is:

> $newnumber = sub @splatter
>                            ~~~~~~~~~~
>   Could not find a parameter named '0'. Supported parameters are: Debug, ErrorAction, ....

Oddly enough, unlike what I'm seeing with these test runbooks, in my 'real-world' workflows, I ***don't*** get this error in the top-level runbook - only when calling the 'child' runbooks from within 'sub'.

```
workflow child
{
    Param ([int]$val)
    Write-Verbose "child: val ($val)"

    $NewNumber = $val*2 
    $NewNumber 
}

workflow childtwo
{
    Param ([int]$val, [int]$valtwo)
    Write-Verbose "childtwo: val ($val) valtwo ($valtwo)"

    $NewNumber = $val * $valtwo 
    $NewNumber 
}

workflow sub 
{ 
    Param ([int]$val)   
    Write-Verbose "sub: val ($val)"

    $splatter = @{ val = $val }
    # works
    $NewNumber = child -val $splatter.val
    # fail
    $NewNumber = child @splatter

    # works
    $NewNumber = childtwo -val $splatter.val -valtwo 2
    # fail
    $NewNumber = childtwo ($splatter + @{ valtwo = 2 })
    $mergeSplatter = ($splatter + @{ valtwo = 2 })
    $NewNumber = childtwo @mergeSplatter
    $twoSplatter = @{ val = $val; valtwo = 2 }
    $NewNumber = childtwo @twoSplatter 

    $NewNumber 
}

workflow super
{
    Param([int]$val)
    Write-Verbose "super: id is $val"

    $splatter = @{ val = $val }

    $newnumber = sub -val $val
    $newnumber = sub @splatter # @ or $ doesn't matter - fails the same

    Write-Verbose "super: newnumber is $newnumber"

    $newnumber
}

super 2
```

Comment: `child @splatter`, not `child $splatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574140.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-21472173969](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574140.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Splatting is not permitted in workflow activities or in calls to workflows.

You will need to either not use splatting or switch the PowerShell Workflow runbook to a [native PowerShell runbook](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-powershell-script-support-azure-automation-2/).

Comment: Thanks Joe, pretty obvious ;-x. But it's weird then, in my real-world scenario, it either seems to work or ignore it, since it's not throwing an error. I can only speculate, but perhaps it's do with how the scripts are compiled (bottom-up?), and are there different stages of compilation where different types of errors would be thrown? After I fixed this problem which appeared to be a 'runtime' issue, I then started getting 'dependent script compilation' errors. All resolved now though, thanks!

Comment: A little more background: these were initially native PS that are being converted (as simply as possible, for now) to workflow activities in order to run them in parallel (at least, more easily than starting new jobs & polling for output). Because there are a few of these runbooks that all accept mostly-the-same parameter sets, I was just trying to whittle them down to reduce as much duplicate code as possible :)